# Help: Insert elements into array in C!

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

Here is my code for merging unique elements from array `B` into array `A`.

For example:

Input: `A={1, 3, 5, 7, 9}`,  `B={2, 4, 6, 9}`

Output: `A={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}`

But I got segmentation fault in line 46. I am assuming it's the array bound problem, but could not figure it out. Any ideas?

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 100
typedef int ElemType;
typedef struct{
    ElemType data[MAXSIZE];
int length;
}SqList;

void CreateList(SqList *L, int n){
L->length=n;
printf("\ninput %d data: ", n);
int i;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d", &L->data[i]);
}   

void PrintList(SqList *L){
int i;
int n;
n=L->length;
printf("\noutput %d data: ", n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d", L->data[i]);
}


ElemType GetElem(SqList *L,int i){
return L->data[i];
}

int LocateElem(SqList *L, ElemType e){
int i;
for(i=1;i<=L->length;i++){
    if(L->data[i]==e){
       return i;
       break;
    }
    else return 0;
}
}

void ListInsert(SqList *L, ElemType e){
int n = L->length;
n++;
L->length=n;     
L->data[n]=e;                        // Segmentation Fault Here !
}


void merge(SqList *La, SqList *Lb){
int i;
ElemType e;
for(i=0;i<Lb->length;i++){
    e=GetElem(&Lb,i);   
    if(!LocateElem(&La,e))
        ListInsert(&La,e);
}
}

int main(){
SqList La,Lb;
int n1,n2;
printf("\nInput number for La: ");
scanf("%d",&n1);
CreateList(&La,n1);
printf("\nInput number for Lb: ");
scanf("%d",&n2);
CreateList(&Lb,n2);
printf("Here is La:\n");
PrintList(&La);
printf("Here is Lb:\n");
PrintList(&Lb);
merge(&La,&Lb);
printf("Here is merged list:\n");
PrintList(&La);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: compiling you're ignoring warnings

Answer (score 2):

You are using some `&` too much in the `merge` code

```
void merge(SqList *La, SqList *Lb){
  int i;
  ElemType e;
  for(i=0;i<Lb->length;i++){
    e=GetElem(Lb,i);   
    if(!LocateElem(La,e))
      ListInsert(La,e);
  }
}
```

then it does not segfault, but I have no checked if the "logic" is right (I suppose it is)

**Add**

Also, the ListInsert needs to be fixed:

```
void ListInsert(SqList *L, ElemType e){
  int n = L->length;
  L->data[n]=e;
  L->length++;
}
```

Your version skip an array element, since you use the "incremented size" to index the new element, while a new inserted value must be put at index `L->length`, and then you need incrementing the length of the array (last element of an array of size N is N-1, so incrementing size to N+1, the last element will have index N).

Of course you do not check array bounds, so you can get trouble if you insert more than MAXSIZE elements.

**Add 2**

Your LocateElem needs fixing too:

```
int LocateElem(SqList *L, ElemType e){
  int i;
  for(i=1;i<=L->length;i++){
    if(L->data[i]==e){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

(I've kept your idea of using 0 as special value for not found, though read the comment about it and the MAXSIZE speach; moreover, more of your code need fixing to use this consistently). Here the fix is about the fact that you returned when you found the first element not equal to e, while (I imagine) you want to return 0 iff you do not find the element, or anything not-0 if you find it. This fixed code explores the whole array (starting from 1, if you reserve the 0 index for special meaning)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am very new to C. You are right. I did use a lot of & and got warning from the compiler. But the function prototypes for GetElem, LocateElem and ListInsert all have pointer type as the first parameter. Shouldn't I use the & in the argument in the function call?

Comment: You have pointers already! in `int func(something *S)` the argument S **is** a pointer, so that when you use it for another function, like `doIt(S)`, you are passing already a pointer, and it's ok if proto for doIt is `void doIt(something *)` or similar. If you use &, you get the address of where the pointer to "something" is stored, that is not what you want.

Comment: @joansky a suggestion: since you're using signed int for indexing, let -1 be the "not found" value, and index the array of size N in the range `[0, N-1]`, as natural for C arrays. Your choice, IMO, is more likely error prone e.g. in LocateElem loop in `[1,N]`, if N=MAXSIZE, you are out bounds by 1, so if you add checks for number of elements, you need checking for less than MAXSIZE-1, or declare your array as `data[MAXSIZE+1]`... as you've done it, your data can be at most 99 (MAXSIZE-1), since one "valid" index (0) is "reserved" for special use... a bit confusing...

Answer (score 1):

You have to check that n does not exceed MAXSIZE. The segmentation fault is most likely caused by a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

if length is n, then only elements 0 up to n-1 should be used. Of course you could also be writing past MAXLIST-1. You should add code to check than L->length <= MAXLIST at all times.

I do wonder why you chose this rather complex approach. And I would rename ListInsert to ListAppend, since you only add to the end of a list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am pretty new to C. Yes, I should rename it to ListAppedn. Do you have any idea how to make the this function not "rather complex"? Thanks!

Comment: Well, perhaps the "rather complex" comment was overdone. I looked at your code again, and it looks fine. The use of so many functions only to do a merge is perhaps overdone, but I assume the functions are also meant to be used in other code.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few errors which may be the cause of your problem:

```
int LocateElem(SqList *L, ElemType e){
int i;
for(i=1;i<=L->length;i++){
    if(L->data[i]==e){           // <-- You need to check data[i-1]
       return i;                 //     since you span [1,length] (off by one)
       break;
    }
    else return 0;               // <-- This goes to outside of the loop,
}                                //     otherwise only the first item is queried
}

void ListInsert(SqList *L, ElemType e){
int n = L->length;
n++;
L->length=n;     
L->data[n]=e;                    // <-- You want to modify data[n-1]
}                                //     since n is already incremented here
```

Comment: Thank you, I was too careless and did not pay attention to these tricks :(

Answer (score 0):

The LocateElem function looks buggy to me. Why does it return 0 if the first test in the loop fails? And why a break after the return statement? A few lines have been shuffled it appears... the break should go and the return 0 moved after the for block.

Comment: ISTM the loop looks wrong: I would use (i = 0; i < L->length; ++i) so there is no need to use L->data[i-1] and the correct i is returned. And indeed, the break is never reached, so useless.

Comment: @Rudy the OP's intention were to use 0 as special value to say not found. Unhappy choice, -1 would have been better... (moreover it's buggy)

Comment: @ShinTakezou: Sorry, I missed that.